# JSON parse throws exception because of renegade apostrophe

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I can't figure out why I'm getting the exception `Unexpected end of JSON input`. I am making a web application in Node JS and am trying to pass a JSON formatted string to the server side. I use JSON.stringify to turn the object into a string and then store it in a form attribute to be submitted to server side. That bit of javascript looks like this:

Javascript (client side)

```
var depString = JSON.stringify(allDepList);
var logString = JSON.stringify(allLog);
hiddenDepList = "<input type='hidden' name='filedata[]' value=" + depString + "/>";
hiddenLog = "<input type='hidden' name='logData[]' value=" + logString + "/>";
form.innerHTML = hiddenLog + hiddenDepList + form.innerHTML;
form.submit(); // submits the form to server
```

HTML for form submission:

```
form#saveForm(method='post', action="http://localhost:3000/project/" + "#{projname}" + "/" + "#{branch}", enctype="x-www-form-urlencoded")
  input#save(type='submit' value="Save")
```

In the console I check my string to check for stray apostrophe's an whatnot and it looks fine. For example, variable logString contains this valid Json string `"[{"msg":"Changed field (licenseid) from (MIT) to (ds). ","date":"23/6/2020 @ 16:47:20"}]"`

However, on my backend I receive the form data in the request body and I see single apostrophes in the data that weren't there before!

Javascript (server side)

```
   const body = req.body;
   jsonStr = body['filedata[]'];
   logStr = body['logData[]'];
   console.log(body);
   console.log(jsonStr);
   console.log(logStr);
```

Output

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'logData[]': '[{"msg":"Changed',  // <--- apostrophe terminates my json string leading to syntax error
  'filedata[]': '[{"pkg":"Newtonsoft.Json","version":"11.0.2","id":"Newtonsoft.Json","licenseid":"nn","flag":false,"approve":false,"comment":"","declared_license_header":"The'
}
```

I would really appreciate any help . I'm a json noob so i wouldnt be surprised if my mistake is very obvious

Comment: Well for starters you can't have a JSON key like 'logData[]'. You can't have square brackets in a key name.

Comment: Also, it's not clear if the JSON string you refer to as "valid" actually has double quotes at the start and end or if you're just denoting the string. If it's the former, then the JSON is *not* valid.

Comment: there are online json format checkers that might help.  Copy the json string into the window, press the validate button.  [here](https://jsonlint.com)

Comment: @seesharper sure you can ~ `{"logData[]": "foo"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```js
"<input ... value=" + depString + "/>"
```

You haven't quoted the `value` attribute so your JSON string value wont be set properly, breaking at the first whitespace character.

The better option would be to create the `<input>` elements and set the `value` property, ie

```js
const depString = JSON.stringify(allDepList);
const logString = JSON.stringify(allLog);

const hiddenDepList = document.createElement('input')
hiddenDepList.type = 'hidden'
hiddenDepList.name = 'filedata[]'
hiddenDepList.value = depString

const hiddenLog = document.createElement('input')
hiddenLog.type = 'hidden'
hiddenLog.name = 'logData[]'
hiddenLog.value = logString

form.append(hiddenLog, hiddenDepList)
form.submit()
```